# issue to swipe view swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

If I want to swipe a lot of `UIView` in a `UIViewController`, what is the best method?

Now the `UIView` after each swipe the hidden property is set to true, so the (for example)second `UIView` is visible. 
But I have a problem because inside the `UIView` I have some `UIButton` and it cover the `UIView` so it's difficult to swipe.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "yourSwipeMethod")

swipe.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down)

self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)

func yourSwipeMethod()
{
      //do something
}
```

Is this what you wanted?